# Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:7.0.0

Tags: android, mapbox-android

After updating android studio 4.2 distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip

got this error

Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:7.0.0

Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-accounts:0.7.0

[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2mqT.png)

[repositories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUL17.png)

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

with recent react-native version update I also faced this issue there are two solutions.

1. Down grade react-native version to 0.64.1.
2. Do the manual installation following this https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/android/install.md